# How can I open a folder without having access to the whole path in a SharePoint library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

So, my question is whether it's possible to grant a group or an individual access to a specific folder nested within another folder they do not have access to in SharePoint. I understand that it can be done, but how can this group or individual access the folder, given that they cannot see the main folder in which it is located and to which they have no access? [image]I don't want to send a link to this group or person because the environment should be used as a document library.

The SharePoint site is a public site so people within the organization do have access to the site.

The picture represents the main page of the document library I created. Let's assume that the 'Business' folder is restricted, meaning not everyone can access and see it. Is it possible to display the folder that the person does have access to inside the 'Business' folder, in the same location where the 'Business' folder currently exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set unique permission for a certain folder, you need to interrupt the inheritance first, and then [share the folder to the users who need it through email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-is-permissions-inheritance). Users who receive the email can jump directly to the folder by clicking the link in the email.

[image]

If the user only has permissions for the 'Business' folder, he can only see the files in that folder, but not other folders at the same level as the 'Business' folder. If you want users to see all the folders they have permission to view in the library, you can first [give the user read permissions to the library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782). Then set unique permission for the folder inside according to actual needs. For example, for those that do not require permissions, remove the user permissions. For those that require permissions, such as the 'Business' folder, you do not need to set it because the read permission has been inherited. If the permission level is not satisfied, you can modify it again.